# How do you add icons into the names of minecraft items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I noticed that Xisumavoid (a minecraft youtuber) has icons in the names of his tools. Like normal minecraft text, these icons are pixelated and the different pixels cannot be different colours. How do I add icons like these to my tools?

Xisumavoid's hermitcraft series in which he has items which have icons in their names.

[image: item with icons in its name]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some emojis can be typed into minecraft and become pixelated. Here's a list of all of them:

⛏⭐⚗❤⚡✎☠⚠⌛⌚⚓✝☃⛄☽☀❄☁⛈☂☔☄☺☹☻☮☯ⓂℹΩ♀♂©®☑☒✔❌⏭⏯⏮⏸⏹⏺⏏◆◇■□⓪①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳ ⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉⅟½⅓¼⅕⅙⅐⅛♫♩♪♬♠♣♥♦⚀⚁⚂⚃⚄⚅→←↓↑←↔☞☜

simply copy the one you want into minecraft to use it.

Comment: Where did you get this list from? Just in case it is updated we know where to look.

Comment: doubt this is _the_ source but this youtube video has the list the answer was pulled from it seems like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBScL3h7iKA but the wiki has it maybe (according to google search page but not present on the page itself) https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Language

Comment: @TankorSmash that actually was my source

Answer (score -3):

Copy Paste from this link:
Click [Here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Language#Unicode)
(press expand)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arqade! 2 things about this answer: 1- link only answers are frowned upon. Please copy paste to arqade any important parts, in case the linked site dissapears or changes their link. 2- if there is already an answer, please post also how your answer is more complete or better than the existing one.